# Bootstrap 4 columns not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a student. And I have used Bootstrap 3.3.7 and after moved to v4.1. In this version, columns are not floating automatically to right. So I used `d-inline-block` class. I created 4 blocks with 3 of columns for each. The number of columns in a row is equal to 12. Then the last column jumps to the new line instead of wrap to the previous column. But this code works fine with Bootstrap 3.3.7. Also, I used 2 columns just for one block, and when the number of columns is smaller than 12, there is no problem. I couldn't find any proper solution on google. Please help. Thank you.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/EshanRajapakshe/3aeaeohb/

My code is:

```
<section class="popular-templates-section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="popular-templates-title">
      <h4>Most Popular Templates</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="popular-templates">

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 d-inline-block">   
        <div class="template-img">
          <img src="assets/images/template-thumb/template-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>      


      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 d-inline-block">   
        <div class="template-img">
          <img src="assets/images/template-thumb/template-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>    

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 d-inline-block">   
        <div class="template-img">
          <img src="assets/images/template-thumb/template-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>   

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 d-inline-block">   
        <div class="template-img">
          <img src="assets/images/template-thumb/template-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>   

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your `.col`s inside a .`row` like this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">6 cols</div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">6 cols</div>
</div>
```

Also remove the `d-inline-block` class from `cols`.

In your particular case:

```
<section class="popular-templates-section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="popular-templates-title">
          <h4>Most Popular Templates</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="popular-templates">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
          <div class="template-img">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/template-thumb/template-1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="template-info">
            <div class="template-name-type">
              <h6 class="template-name">Web Design Inspiration</h6>
              <h6 class="template-type">HTML5 Template</h6>
              <h6 class="template-more-details">MORE DETAILS</h6>
            </div>

            <div class="template-price-type">
              <h5 class="template-price">$78</h5>

              <div class="template-type-icons">
                <img src="assets/images/icons/responsive-devices.png" alt="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Responsive Website">
                <img src="assets/images/icons/bootstrap.png" alt="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Bootstrap 4 Template">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
          <div class="template-img">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/template-thumb/template-1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="template-info">
            <div class="template-name-type">
              <h6 class="template-name">Web Design Inspiration</h6>
              <h6 class="template-type">HTML5 Template</h6>
              <h6 class="template-more-details">MORE DETAILS</h6>
            </div>

            <div class="template-price-type">
              <h5 class="template-price">$78</h5>

              <div class="template-type-icons">
                <img src="assets/images/icons/responsive-devices.png" alt="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Responsive Website">
                <img src="assets/images/icons/bootstrap.png" alt="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Bootstrap 4 Template">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
          <div class="template-img">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/template-thumb/template-1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="template-info">
            <div class="template-name-type">
              <h6 class="template-name">Web Design Inspiration</h6>
              <h6 class="template-type">HTML5 Template</h6>
              <h6 class="template-more-details">MORE DETAILS</h6>
            </div>

            <div class="template-price-type">
              <h5 class="template-price">$78</h5>

              <div class="template-type-icons">
                <img src="assets/images/icons/responsive-devices.png" alt="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Responsive Website">
                <img src="assets/images/icons/bootstrap.png" alt="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Bootstrap 4 Template">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
          <div class="template-img">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/template-thumb/template-1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="template-info">
            <div class="template-name-type">
              <h6 class="template-name">Web Design Inspiration</h6>
              <h6 class="template-type">HTML5 Template</h6>
              <h6 class="template-more-details">MORE DETAILS</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="template-price-type">
              <h5 class="template-price">$78</h5>
              <div class="template-type-icons">
                <img src="assets/images/icons/responsive-devices.png" alt="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Responsive Website">
                <img src="assets/images/icons/bootstrap.png" alt="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Bootstrap 4 Template">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Also added the class `img-fluid` to `img`s so it won't be bigger than its container.

[**Bootstrap-v4 Grid system Docs**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

Comment: Sir I  really appreciate your help. But unfortunately this method not  work for me. If you could go and see this link it would be big help. Please let me know what are the problems with my site. http://mockup-test.tk/

Comment: I have added .row class and removed  .d-inline-block class. Also add .img-fluid class. Not working sir. Please see my site through this link and be kind to tell me what are the problems there. Thank you. http://mockup-test.tk

Comment: @EshanRajapakshe Check it out now, edited the answer. Every time you use a `col` the parent must be a `row` in bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/gautamnaik1994/voonscad/)

I edited ur html, removed un necessary classes.
Also if u want all columns to be of same size on all devices, u only need one `col-{number}` class

Also there is no `col-xs-{class}` in bootstrap 4. Instead of that, use `col-{number}`

```
<section class="popular-templates-section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="popular-templates-title">
      <h4>Most Popular Templates</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="popular-templates">
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-3 blue">
          <div class="template-img">
            <img src="assets/images/template-thumb/template-1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 black">
          <div class="template-img">
            <img src="assets/images/template-thumb/template-1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3 blue">
          <div class="template-img">
            <img src="assets/images/template-thumb/template-1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3 black">
          <div class="template-img">
            <img src="assets/images/template-thumb/template-1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are facing issues basically because of the improper semantics of Bootstrap grid used by you. Find below the corrected code, it will help for sure.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Akash Kumar">
  <meta name="url" content="http://akashshivanand.com">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    .blue {
      padding: 5px;
      background: blue;
    }
    
    .black {
      padding: 5px;
      background: black;
    }
  </style>
  <title> by EshanRajapakshe</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="popular-templates-section">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="popular-templates-title">
            <h4>Most Popular Templates</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="popular-templates">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 d-inline-block blue">
                <div class="template-img">
                  <img src="assets/images/template-thumb/template-1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 d-inline-block black">
                <div class="template-img">
                  <img src="assets/images/template-thumb/template-1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 d-inline-block blue">
                <div class="template-img">
                  <img src="assets/images/template-thumb/template-1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 d-inline-block black">
                <div class="template-img">
                  <img src="assets/images/template-thumb/template-1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```